# Next.js - how to set head tags dynamically

Tags: reactjs, next.js, seo

This question involves `next-seo` library.

I am using a default config per the docs and attempting to override `og:image`, `og:title`, `og:url`, `title` for each product on an e-commerce site. When I inspect the `<head/>` element in devtools the correct tag injections are taking place. However, when using the Twitter and Facebook sharing debuggers these dynamic changes are not being scraped. I assumed functionality like this is core to this library and I wonder if I am overlooking something.

I implement my defaults in `_app.js` and inserting my per product overrides as high up my render tree as possible.

**Default**

```
export default {
  titleTemplate: `Anne's Handmade | %s`,
  title: 'Home',
  description: 'One of a kind, handmade jewelry @ affordable prices. ',
  canonical: 'https://anneshandmade.herokuapp.com/',
  facebook: {
    appId: '2300738536877547'
  },
  openGraph: {
    type: 'website',
    url: 'https://anneshandmade.herokuapp.com/',
    title: "Anne's Handmade | Home",
    description: 'One of a kind, handmade jewelry @ affordable prices. ',
    site_name: "Anne's Handmade",
    images: [
      {
        url: 'https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/shopping-site/assets/open-graph-2.jpeg',
        width: '800',
        height: '800',
        alt: "Anne's Handmade Logo"
      }
    ]
  },
  twitter: {
    handle: '@BenjaminBrooke3',
    site: '@BenjaminBrooke3',
    cardType: 'summary_large_image'
  }
}
```

**_app.js**

```
      <Container>
        <NextSeo config={SEO} />
        <ApolloProvider client={apollo}>
          <Page {...pageProps}>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </Page>
        </ApolloProvider>
      </Container>
```

**Overrider per product**

```
     const { product, thumbIndex } = data
        return (
          <>
            <NextSeo
              config={{
                title: product.title,
                openGraph: {
                  title: `Anne's Handmade | ${product.title}`,
                  url: `https://anneshandmade.herokuapp.com/product?id=${product.id}`,
                  images: [
                    {
                      url: product.images[0],
                      width: 800,
                      height: 800,
                      alt: product.title
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }}
            />
            <ProductStyles>
              <Thumbnails images={product.images} thumbIndex={thumbIndex} />
              <LargeImage image={product.images[thumbIndex]} />
              <ProductDetail product={product} user={user} />
            </ProductStyles>
          </>
        )
```

**Head**

[image]

Is there something special that needs to be done when using a query param?

**Facebook Sharing Debugger**

[image]

Facebook shows both urls in redirects, but when I look at what the scraper actually returns, it is still the original default image, url, etc.

Comment: Strange. I use `next-seo` for almost all sites and it always seems to work with SSR.

Comment: Did you ever get this right? I am facing this issue too.